# Can't declare variable in switch case

Tags: c, switch-statement, label, declaration

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int a = 4;
    switch (a)
    {
        case 4:
            int res = 1;
            printf("%d",res);
        break;

    }
}
```

When I compiled this code with gcc I got error

```
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# gcc test.c -o t
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:9:4: error: a label can only be part of a statement and a declaration is not a statement
    int res = 1;
```

But when I add `;` like `case 4:;` I can compile my code.

What is the problem and why `;` fix that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Opposite to C++, in C declarations are not statements and labels may precede only statements.

Placing a null statement after the label

```
case 4:;
```

you made that the label does not precede now a declaration.

Another approach is to use a compound statement after the label and to place the declaration inside the compound statement like

```
    case 4:
    {  
        int res = 1;
        printf("%d",res);
        break;
    }
```

Comment: But is that right fix to this error? is that can make me problem?

Comment: @yokjc232 There will be no problem for the code snippet you showed.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is in your error message: labels can only be attached to statements and a declaration is not a statement.

Seeing [N1570](http://chimera.roma1.infn.it/SP/COMMON/iso-iec-9899-1990.pdf) 6.8.2 Compound statement, there are `declaration` and `statement` enumerated separately, and it is suggesting that they are different things.

> ```
> Syntax
> 1     compound-statement:
>           { block-item-listopt }
>
>       block-item-list:
>           block-item
>           block-item-list block-item
>
>       block-item:
>           declaration
>           statement
> ```

The `;` in `case 4:;` is *a null statement* (defined in N1570 6.8.3 Expression and null statements), which is a statement, and thus it is allowed.

Comment: But is that right fix to this error? is that can make me problem?

Answer (score 3):

> What is the problem and why ; fix that?

The problem is just what the error message says.  Your `case 4:` is a label.  Labels identify the immediately-following *statement*, and therefore must immediately precede a statement.  Declarations such as `int res = 1;` are not statements.

On the other hand, adding a semicolon creates an *empty statement*, which, as its name implies, is a statement, and therefore can be labeled.  That's why it solves the problem.

With that said, I'd rate the semicolon solution poor style.  I'd also rate declaring a variable whose enclosing block is the body of a `switch` as poor style, and that one can bite you in other ways, too.  Consider instead moving the declaration of `res` outside the `switch` ...

```
int a = 4;
int res = 1;
switch (a) {
    case 4:
        printf("%d",res);
    break;
}
```

... or enclosing it in an inner block (which is a *compound statement*, and therefore can be labeled) ...

```
int a = 4;
switch (a) {
    case 4: {
        int res = 1;
        printf("%d",res);
        break;
    }
}
```

.